# swing - How to set assign a Tabbed Pane Tab a Button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtabbedpane

So I've been looking at the JTabbedPane feature in Swing recently, and it looks very appealing. However, instead of having those tabs that are default, I want to know if it's possible to assign them to buttons. In the image below, I have my navigation menu on the left of my GUI. Those images are JButtons, and essentially what I want to happen, is when you click a certain JButton, it opens a different Tabbed Pane. Is this possible?

[Navigation Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNqBo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> essentially what I want to happen, is when you click a certain JButton, it opens a different Tabbed Pane. Is this possible?

Sure, you can add the panel containing the buttons to the BorderLayout.LINE_START of the frame. Then you create another panel that uses a `CardLayout` and add this panel to the BorderLayout.CENTER of the frame.

Then you add all the panels to the card layout.

Finally you add an ActionListener to each button to display the appropriate panel when a button is clicked.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out.

Comment: So I tried what you mentioned, and so far it's worked great. However for some reason, the last component I add to one of my JPanels is always centered to the left. I have no idea why. Image: i.imgur.com/3872UQt.png. The component I added last was the search icon, towards the bottom in the image linked. Here is my code for that JPanel class on the right: bit.ly/2gqcBwJ. Here is my Window class that manages the BorderLayout: bit.ly/2gI7vwe. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is also only happening in that JPanel. Not the others for some reason, I have no idea why. Could it be because it is on the center border layout position or something? @camickr

Comment: The problem would be your layout manager. But I have no idea what your code looks like so I can't make any suggestions on how to fix it.   Create a proper [mcve] to try to replicate the problem. If you can't solve the problem then you have simple code to post when you ask another question. The original question you asked is solved.